# how to make javascript requests using login information from another site

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, cross-domain

I have the following scenario. I have a website A running node.js where users can login and then perform tasks using various javascript API calls. When they login I assign them a cookie that is used when making all web requests and in this way I can track how many requests they have already made.

Now I want another site B to also be able to consume the API provided by site A. The question that I have is how can the users on site B obtain the cookie that will allow them to make requests to site A, without going to site A and login there. If I make a cross-domain GET request to login using some default account, I cannot extract from it the cookies assigned in the response.

If possible, I would avoid using something like a SECRET_KEY parameter in the get requests from site B to A since I use node-session module which loads sessions based on the cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do it is either make site A send back wildcard cookies that include both domain A and domain B.  Keep in mind that you might open up a big security hole by doing so if your domain A and domain B are both second level domains.

Or make code on domain B use client's browser as a channel to domain A.  You can send Javascript code from domain B to user browser that will consume the API on domain A and ferry back the results to domain B.  But, even in this case you have to take care of CORS headers on both sides. Otherwise browser will not trust the code from domain B to send requests to domain A.